# CSS Id selector stops all content from showing in Xamarin.Forms WebView on Android 10

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a `WebView` that I assign an HTML snippet to using `HtmlWebViewSource` assigned to `Source`.

Since targeting Android 10, the `WebView` has stopped showing all content.

I have narrowed down one character that makes the difference between content showing and not showing content. The HTML contains a `<style>` section. If it contains...

```
hello {}
```

... then the content shows. Where as if it contains...

```
#hello {}
```

... then no content shows. (`hello` doesn't refer to anything.)

Obviously, the # character indicates an Id selector.

So, why would targeting Android 10 suddenly make my HTML stop showing based on such a simple change in CSS?

I narrowed it down further. In the `<head>` tag...

`<style>#</style>` -> No HTML shows

`<style></style>` -> HTML shows.

`<style>.</style>` -> HTML shows.

I'm still on Xamarin.Forms 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. I'm using a class derived from `WebView` with a custom renderer, which was inheriting from...

```
ViewRenderer<MyWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
```

I'm not sure why I did this. It at least enables one to refer to methods on the renderer from a related class (which handles Javascript) without having to cast `Element` on the renderer to the custom class derived from `WebView`.

So, I made the custom renderer inherit from standard `WebViewRenderer` instead and removed my code that created the native control and that loaded its HTML snippet, which is now handled automatically. Customisation of the native `WebView` is as before.

I have no idea why I can no longer create my own native `WebView` without getting this strange bug.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me. Please check it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Style the element with the id "hello" */
#hello {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style all elements with the class name "Line" */
.Line {
  background-color: #9815B0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- An element with a unique id -->
<h1 id="hello">Page1</h1>

<!-- Multiple elements with same class -->
<h2 class="Line">Line1</h2>
<p>number 1.</p>

<h2 class="Line">Line2</h2>
<p>number 2.</p>

<h2 class="Line">Line3</h2>
<p>number 3.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see the text when I remove the contents of the <style> tag. I think I will try Xamarin.Forms 5.

Comment: I actually have several WebViews. Each one is contained in an AbsoluteLayout and then the set of layouts is assigned to the data source of this control https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView . The reason I'm using HTML snippets is because this set up crashed when I tried to set the Url of every WebView. So it's UI intensive.